# Only last item in listview displayed in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am trying to parse the following json

```
{
"effect_list": [{
      "1":[  
         {  
            "effects_id":"1",
            "effects_name":"Band 1"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"2",
            "effects_name":"Band 2"
         }


      ],
      "2": [ 
         {  
            "effects_id":"4",
            "effects_name":"Background Blur"
         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"5",
            "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
         }
      ] 
   }]
}
```

My BaseAdapter shows only last Item in the ListView.I am trying to retrieve values in Map. During iteration the values gets override. When I print the key and values, all the values are displayed properly. It shows complete keys and values.

What am I doing wrong here?

**MyContactAdapter2.java**

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
        List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;


        // Constructors
        public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {

            this.context = context;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            contactList = objects;
        }

        public MyContactAdapter2() {
            System.out.println("hai");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = contactList.size();
            System.out.println("Count size" + count);
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<EffectList>> getItem(int position) {
            return contactList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            System.out.println(10);


            final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
            if (convertView == null) {
                View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
                vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
                view.setTag(vh);

            } else {
                vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }





            for (Map<String, List<EffectList>> map : contactList) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    Object value = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("key :" + key + "value :" + value);

                        EffectList item = getItem(position).get(key).get(0);

                        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
                        vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());

                }
            }


            return vh.rootView;
        }


        private static class ViewHolder {
            public final RelativeLayout rootView;
            public final ImageView imageView;
            public final TextView textViewName;
            public final TextView textViewEmail;

            private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
                this.rootView = rootView;
                this.imageView = imageView;
                this.textViewName = textViewName;
                this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
            }

            public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
                return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am a bit confused with your model. What are you trying to display in your `ListView`? Could you post a screenshot above?

Comment: apart from this question , you should never use in loop statements inside your `adapter` `getView`

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in this part of the code:

```
        for (Map<String, List<EffectList>> map : contactList) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<EffectList>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("key :" + key + "value :" + value);

                    EffectList item = getItem(position).get(key).get(0);

                    vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
                    vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());

            }
        }
```

For every list item, you are setting the key and value one after the other. so at the end of the for loop, only the last one remains.

For eg: Contact list - {you, me, dupree}
what you are doing is

1. vh.textViewName(you)
2. vh.textViewName(me)
3. vh.textViewName(dupree)

So you will always see dupree in your list.

---

Instead of creating MyContactAdapter2 with contactList pass the `Map<String, List<EffectList>> map` directly

If you only want to show textViewName and textViewEmail on your list. Then create a list of objects containing name and email.

```
class Contact {
public String name;
public String email;
}

List<Contact> contacts;
```

Now pass this contacts to the adapter. Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you pls give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
EffectList item = getItem(position).get(key).get(0);
```

`getItem(position)` will return u a `Map < String, List < EffectList>>`

`getItem(position).get(key)` will return you `List< EffectList >` for that particular key.

`getItem(position).get(key).get(0)` will always return you element at zero position in the list. `List< EffectList >`.

So, simple solution is just get the proper position from the list instead of hardcoding it to `get(0)`..